# How to get RequireJS to act like a Script tag

Tags: requirejs

I'm relatively new to RequireJS and I think I understand modules and use of "define". However, it is unclear to me how I can take JS with an existing Script tag on my page and move that code--verbatim--into a separate JS file then use Require to load it in such a way that it runs just as it would if it were on the HTML page in a Script tag as such:

```
<script> ... js code here ... </script>
```

Like a Script tag, I would want the script to run before or as the page is presented to the user.

I'm trying to keep this question as generic as possible because I would think this is a question many beginners might have...

Thank you.